# How do I reference a Changeset in a TFS Build script?

Tags: tfsbuild

How do I reference a Changeset in a TFS Build script?

I want to write a TFS Build workflow that only copies the files referenced in the current changeset. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could call the `tfpt` power tool from the Team Foundation Server Power Tools to run `tfpt getcs /changeset:12345`. You'll need to create a temporary mapping for that first. You can use `tf workspace` and `tf workfold` to set that up.

Use a powershell script or a InvokeProcess activity to run these.

Comment: How do you get the number to the current changeset inside the workflow?

Comment: It's in the `GetVersion` argument of the build.